# MS Office: How can I replace all occurrences of a word by a symbol?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I want to replace all occurrences of '*' by the multiplication symbol (the slanted cross symbol that looks like an X (but is not quite an X)) in a Powerpoint application, but the Find/Replace dialog seems to only take plain text as a replacement (I did past the symbol there, but after the replacement, only a funny character with a question mark appeared). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by multiplication symbol? Have you tried pasting the symbol in the "replace with" text box?

Comment: I mean the slanted cross symbol that looks like an X (but is not quite an X). I pasted it on the dialog but it gets converted into a funny-looking thing I don't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Non-ASCII symbols are dependent on support from the font to display correctly. Copy and paste the correct symbol into the find-and-replace dialog's "replace" box (you can use `×` which is the correct unicode `U+00D7` symbol) ignoring if it appears incorrectly in the replace box and do a "Replace All"

If the font on your slides supports this symbol, it should appear correctly (again, it's OK if it appears funny or as a box or anything in the find-and-replace dialog when you paste it so long as you have a sufficiently-modern version of Microsoft PowerPoint). If not, simply change the font on your slides to one that contains support for this symbol.

Comment: But then manually changing the font on my slides at the point of each occurrence of the symbol would be a lot of work, and not very differently from simply selecting the old text and pasting the symbol over it, correct?

Comment: No, just change the font in the master template.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that works. The slides are all in the same font. If I copy the symbol from one part of the slide and use find/replace to replace it in another part of the same slide (which therefore has the same font as the original part), it still does not work.